# How can I get all the requisitionList of a customer in an observer Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

First of all, I want to get all the requisitionList of a customer by customer id and then I need to check whether a particular requisition list exists or not?

If anyone has used the requisition list functionality of the enterprise edition of Magento 2?

Thanks in advance.